# How I can use the .so File of another project into my own project

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, .so

I want to use .so lib file of another project into my own project.
There i am facing some problems i have put the .so file in JNILibs folder.
but the native methods in the .so file did not successfully loaded and give error that the Can not find the corresponding JNI Function.
so how i can solve this problem i have checked different solutions like
[Call shared library (.so) methods within Android Studios C files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045260/call-shared-library-so-methods-within-android-studios-c-files)
[How do I package .so files into my .aar archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803921/how-do-i-package-so-files-into-my-aar-archive)

but they did not solve my problem.
i have no .cpp file nor .h file.
I have only .so file so how i can solve this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk to the developer of the other project. After all, this project must be open source, as only developers with no ethics would pirate a `.so` from some other app. The developers of the other project can help you navigate the open source code to find the relevant material, such as their Java class that has their JNI bridge code.

Comment: ok but i have problem including my.so file in .mk file and gradle

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422873/192373